Digital Ocean Droplet & Docker Port-Mapping, Axios Default URL Issue
I am running four Docker containers on a digital ocean droplet. A react frontend, a django backend, a Postgres database, and pg_admin GUI.
In my frontend, I'm using an axios default URL to syphon my frontend requests to specific API's.
On my computer, when in development, when my axios default URL is this, the app works, and the frontend successfully makes request to the backend, and so on to the database:
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8000/api/";

When I run it on the digital ocean droplet, and change my axios default URL to this, it works the same way:
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://<<insert-droplet-ipv4 address>>:8000/api/";


However...I am trying to not expose my backend & my database to the public internet, to avoid brute force attacks that I've been encountering.
My only UFW rule on my droplet is to allow ssh logging in to port 22 from my home computer:
22/tcp                     ALLOW       <<insert home IP address>>

**What do I need to do, to insure that my app continues to work when I deploy it on the droplet...and the only container accessible to the public internet is my frontend container, and my frontend container can still communicate with the backend, and the backend with the database inside the droplet. **
I've tried to change the axios default URL to this, but when I do this, the frontend does not successfully make requests:
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://backend:8000/api/";


My docker-compose is as such
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres

    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=user@domain.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin
    depends_on:
      - db

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app/frontend

    depends_on:
      - backend

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres

    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app/backend

    depends_on:
      - db


I've tried to change the Axios Default URL, and I've not succeeded.
